# Can a subgroup be a subfield but not a subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I was doing my homework and came across a question with several true or false parts. One of the parts asked the question, "Every subring of $\mathbb{C}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$", which I assumed was false, and the next part asked, "Every subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$", which I assumed was true. The solution I found was the opposite, though; the first suggestion was labeled true and the second false.

I assumed the first statement was false because the working definition I have of a field is, 'a subring that has inverses', which would imply that if something is a field then it is also a ring. It also tells me that a group being a subring is not sufficient to prove the group a subfield. What am I missing, and are there any good examples that prove the truth or falsity

Comment: You're right -- the solutions have a typo.

Comment: Don't know where you "found" the solution: you are correct. Also: I don't think you mean "group": I think you mean "subset".

Comment: $\mathbf Z$ is not a subfield of $\mathbf C$, albeit it's a subring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every field is a ring, so a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ is in particular a subring.

$\mathbb{Z}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$ which is not a field.